# How to tell the importance of regression coefficients when both continuous and binary features exist

Tags: regression-coefficients

Let's say I have 3 features for a regression model: if_smoking, if_drinking, and body_height. The first 2 are binary, while the 3rd is continuous. I have coefficients like:

bias/y_intercept: 1.2

coefficient for if_smoking: 0.8

coefficient for if_drinking: 0.5

coefficient for body_height: 0.2

The model, therefore, should be:
y_predict = 1.2 + 0.8*if_smoking + 0.5*if_drinking + 0.2*body_height

I can say that if_smoking is more important than if_drinking since the former's coefficient is 0.8 over the latter's 0.5, **and both are binary (0 or 1)**.

However, is body_height more or less important than if_smoking and if_drinking? If I look at the coefficient, it's 0.2, less than if_smoking's 0.8 and if_drinking's 0.5. However, **body_height is continuous**. Let's say a person's height is 5 feet, 0.2*5 is greater than if_smoking's 0.8*1 and if_drinking's 0.5*1. In other words, body_height's coefficient (0.2) is smaller but its overall contribution (0.2*5=1) is larger.

So, do I say body_height is less or more important than if_smoking and if_drinking?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "important."  There are several natural interpretations but it is not evident which you might have in mind.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for asking. I basically referred to the feature importance - e.g., it sounds like, as a feature, if_smoking is more important than if_drinking, but not sure how to interpret the importance when there's a mix of binary and continuous features.

Comment: Your comment provides no further clarification about what you mean by "importance".

Comment: @dipetkov Does this make sense: relative magnitude of the effects of different independent variables

Comment: One aspect that can make quite a bit of difference: Do you want to estimate "importance" for each predictor conditional or unconditional on the other predictors?

Comment: @dipetkov I would say unconditional, i.e., all predictors are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that with "importance" you have something similar to the [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) of the various independent variables (IV) in mind. I.e. you wonder how large the change in the dependent variable (DV) `y_predict` is when changing one of the IVs by "a unit".

Then, the fitted coefficient of an IV tells you how much `y_predict` changes by changing the IV by one unit, *and keeping all the other IVs fixed*. E.g., if you change the IV `if_smoking` from zero to one and keep all the other IVs fixed, the DV `y_predict` will on average increase by 0.8.

Similarly, the coefficient 0.2 of `body_height` means that an increase in body height by one unit, i.e. one foot, would lead to `y_predict` increasing by 0.2. But the unit foot is quite huge for body height. A more reasonable change of e.g. 0.1 feet would result in an average change of `y_predict` of only 0.02. Thus, I would argue that the body height is, in comparison to the other IVs, not very "important", i.e. doesn't have as large an effect on `y_predict`.

**Summary**: Always mind your units. The coefficients can only be interpreted with the units in mind. If you had e.g. used the unit millimeter, the coefficient would have increased to 60.96, for exactly the same data and thus the same "importance" (effect).

Comment: The effect size, by definition, uses units determined by the spreads of the data rather than arbitrary anthropocentric units like feet.  You seem to describe the estimated coefficients, which -- because they are potentially based on different units of measurement -- aren't even comparable.

Comment: @whuber I was referring to effect size in the sense of my posted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size), which puts it very loosely. If there is a standard definition of effect size, could you share a link?

Comment: Cohen, Jacob. 1988. Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences. Second. New York: Routledge. https://doi.org/10.4324/9780203771587.

Comment: @frank Thanks for the input. Yes, I agreed that the units were critical to interpret the coefficients. I did see something called "standardized coefficients", which used the standard deviation units. However, I have both continuous and binary features. Do I standardize the binary features together with the continuous features? Or do I have to compare continuous features and binary features separately?

Comment: I don't know what you refer to by "standardized coefficients". I just think that a straightforward approach would be that you choose a reasonable change $c_b$ for `body_height`, compute the belonging change $c_y = 0.2 * c_b$ in `y_predict` and then report the pair $(c_b, c_y)$, together with the belonging units, and then leave it to the audience to decide whether they think this is more or less "important" than the change in `y_predict` when e.g. changing the variable `if_smoking`.